# OpenGL GLX_EXT_swap_control exists but can't link functions

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, nvidia

I can't use glXSwapBufferEXT in my code, I get undeclared identifier. But for instance glXQueryDrawable works.

In my cmake file I'm linking Opengl libraries, and including them for the compiler.

In my header I'm including GL/glx.h and GL/glxext.h.

Running glxinfo shows GLX_EXT_swap_control exists, and testing extensions in my app also shows its existence in runtime.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

I have NVIDIA 346.47 drivers installed for Quadro K5000

Linux gcc4.9/clang3.5

Comment: Please tell me why my question has been down voted? I see it has been edited, sorry, its my 3rd post here. But instead of just editing and down voting you can explain and teach for future improvement, and not just slap and leave. Thanks.

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the compilation command you're using for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the *extension mechanism* to query the function pointer in runtime, trying to directly link to a glX 
extension function is not guaranteed to work.

Note that I assume you want `glXSwapIntervalEXT` instead of the `glXSwapBufferEXT` since the latter doesn't exist and the former is the only function defined in `GLX_EXT_swap_control`, so you probably mean that.

If you want to do this manually, you should grab the [latest `glxext.h` from opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glxext.h) for the definition of the `PFNGLXSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC` pointer type, and use it like this:

```
#include "glxext.h"

/* function pointer for glXSwapIntervalEXT */
PFNGLXSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC glXSwapIntervalEXT=NULL;

/* later in your code */
if (/* GLX_EXT_swap_control supported */) {
   glXSwapIntervalEXT=(PFNGLXSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)glXGetProcAddressARB((const GLubyte*)"glXSwapIntervalEXT");
}

/* Later, you can use it as if it were a function.
   You'll need a GL context for that */
glXSwapIntervalEXT(1);
```

However, doing this manually adds lots of boilerplate code. You should consider using an [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), which besides GL extnesions also handles `glX` and `wgl` extensions, and does all of that for you under the hood.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this mechanism much better now.